# Select from same table and via subtable to one result set

Tags: mysql, sql

This setup is for multiple addresses for one debtor. I have 2 fields for the debtor in my order table. debiteur_id for the "default" value from the debtor table. If we choose another addres for the same debtor the debiteur_id is null and aditional_id is filled in with the value from aditional_debiteur wich is linked to debtor. I hope someone gets it.

My tables:

```
Order
id debiteur_id amount aditional_id
1  null        2      1
2  1           3      null
3  2           1      null

debtor
id name         hnr place
1  myname       10  london
2  companyName  4   Enschede

Aditional_debiteur
id debiteur_id hnr place
1  1           22  amsterdam
```

What I want is to get all the orders linked (Direct or inderict) to an id from the debtor table. This because the order is from the same company only with another adress.
If I choose debor with id 1 I get this order results:

```
order_id name    amount 
1        myname  2
2        myname  3
```

**Another result with debtor id 2:**

```
order_id name         amount 
3        companyName  1
```

I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `Order` WHERE `debiteur_id` = '1' ORDER BY `id` ASC
```

This returns the result with the default debtor adress, I want to retrieve the other orders with the aditional_id (wich are linked to the debtor with the debituer_id) also.

Long story short. I want to retrieve all orders from the order table with an specific debtor from the debtor table.

Comment: I think I get it but how about showing us your expected result based on your example data

Comment: @Matt I have added one result. But I will add another one.

Comment: never mind it wasn't clear that was your desired result, from your narration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    o.id AS order_id
    ,d.name
    ,o.amount
    ,IFNULL(ad.hnr,d.hnr) AS hnr
FROM
    `Order` o
    LEFT JOIN Additional_debiteur ad
    ON o.aditional_id = ad.id
    AND ad.debiteur_id = 1
    INNER JOIN debtor d
    ON IFNULL(o.debiteur_id,ad.debiteur_id) = d.id
WHERE
    o.debiteur_id = 1
    OR ad.id IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
    o.id ASC
```

Here is one way to do it.

Comment: Wow thank you so much!! That's a great query! Can I ask you one more question?

Comment: sure what's the follow up?

Comment: How can I get the hnr and place in the select? Because it must come from different tables.

Comment: you can use a long case statement but because precedence would be on additional_debiteur's hnr you could just do this: ,IFNULL(ad.hnr,d.hnr) AS hnr

Comment: Ah I get the point. IFNULL is a handy thing:) Learnt something new today. Thank you Matt!!

Comment: COALESCE is also handy and encompasses ifnull.  ifnull is fine for 2 values but when you want to compare more use coalesce http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/functions/coalesce.php

Comment: Good to know! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want `OR`?

```
SELECT o.*
FROM `Order` o
WHERE 1 IN (debiteur_id, aditional_id)
ORDER BY id ASC
```

Note:  If the ids are numeric, then you should not use single quotes for the values.  I am assuming that the ids are, in fact, numeric.

Comment: aditional_id is the row id from the Aditional_debiteur
table. I need the Aditional_debiteur. debiteur_id then it is correct.